# Python SQLite math functions (no such function: SQRT)

Tags: python, sqlite

With Python 3.11 I try to use math function (sqrt) with SQLite SQL query. Let's say:

```
import sqlite3 as sq
import pandas as pd
con = sq.connect('database.db')
query = "SELECT SQRT(value) FROM table;"
pd.read_sql_query(query, con, index_col=None)
```

It throws "no such function: SQRT" in my local python environment. However when I use Jupyter Lab (same sqlite3 version - 3.39.3) or DB Browser it works with exactly the same database. So I have a proof that it can be done.

I've seen that by default sqlite is built without "math" flag as in: [SQLite3 math functions Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451170/sqlite3-math-functions-python)
However sqlite is delivered as a part of Python standard library so I probably should rebuild my Python installation. Hence the question:

How can I configure python to use sqlite with built-in support for math functions?

Comment: Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74619055/8508004), but I think it is suggesting compiling  SQLite with the option on to enable math functions and not Python?

Comment: SQLite is built-in in Python. I probably need to rebuild/reconfigure Python or use different/external engine to connect to the database, but I can't find the information on how to do it.

Comment: [This](https://bugs.python.org/issue42686) and [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/86852), I think, says they were going to leave it enabled, at least in Windows. And talks about macOS. It's certainly weird that it's not working. However, I cannot find a 3.11 bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting around this by defining my own functions:

```
import math

conn = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')
conn.create_function('sqrt', 1, math.sqrt)
```